# Is it possible to use nmap functionalities in C++?

Tags: c++, integration, nmap

I want to invoke [nmap](https://nmap.org/) functionalities like OS detection in C++.

In python, `import nmap` allows to use nmap functions. Similarly, is there any way I can do it in C++?

Comment: No, there isn't a shared library available. You can use subprocess invocation anyway.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi How to use the subprocess invocation? Can you please elaborate

Comment: It's just as simple as starting a child process. Please search before asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any ideas on how to integrate with nmap programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735001/any-ideas-on-how-to-integrate-with-nmap-programatically)

Answer (score 4):

You can run the nmap as an external program and read its output through a pipe using popen().

Example

```
FILE *pin = popen("nmap -p 123 10.0.1.0/24","r");
if ( pin ) {
   while (!feof(pin)) {
      const char *line = readLine(pin);
      printf("%s\n", line);
   }
   pclose(pin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python `nmap` package simply launches the Nmap command and parses the [XML output](https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-xml-output.html). This is certainly something you could do in C++, though you'd have to work out the parsing yourself. I'm not aware of an existing Nmap-output-parsing library in C or C++ like there are for Python, Perl, Ruby, etc.